# Rescorla Wagner and Classical Conditioning

Tags: conditioning

I have one question regarding Classical Conditioning versus Operant Conditioning. I guess I do understand the difference but there are some things that are not quite clear: Why is the Rescorla-Wagner Model always taught with respect to classical conditioning and Actor-Crtique with respect to operant conditioning? Couldn`t I also use RW to update S-R associations (eg in operant conditioning).
Secondly, when I learn an association that after eating apples I feel sick, is this an example of classical or operant conditioning? On the one hand, I learn an expectation on the apples but on the other hand the "reward" of sicknes is contingent of my action (of eating). I guess I could model that with RW?

Thank you Laurie

Comment: I really just think of classical vs operant as being involuntary vs voluntary, respectively (there are other differences but that's the crux).  While eating an apple can appear to result in *both* classical and operant learning, for study design, it's important to break paradigms down to their components: Apple (stimulus) -> *nausea* (response; involuntary) = classical.  Apple (stimulus) -> *eating* (response; voluntary) = operant; note that operant conditioning does not require a cue, so just reduction in apple-eating qualifies.